# using QueryString in ASPX file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use sql command in ASPX file to capture a querysring value but having some syntax issue. Everything works fine but when i try to filter it by querystring then i get the syntax issue.  How can i filter it my query using the querystring?   Here is my code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DD_AI_DS" runat="server" 
              ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
              SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [MyField] FROM [MyTable] where ID = '"+request.querystring[ID]+"' order by ID asc" >
          </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: `QueryStringParameter`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.querystringparameter.aspx

Comment: This code is open to a SQL Injection attack - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Comment: i had to add this <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="Post_ID" 
                Type="String" />

Comment: Moe, if this is the solution, you can post it as an answer.

Comment: I updated my accepted answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DD_AI_DS" runat="server" 
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [MyField] FROM [MyTable] where ID = @ID order by ID asc" >
   <SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="ID" QueryStringField="Post_ID" Type="String" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

As an aside, if the code you had written had actually worked then it would have created a security hole in your website by allowing sql injection. I would read up on this topic so you don't accidentally make your websites open to hackers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the `SqlDataSource` properties in code-behind, like this:

```
DD_AI_DS.SelectCommand = "SELECT DISTINCT [MyField] FROM [MyTable] where ID = '"+ Request.QueryString[ID] + "' order by ID asc";
DD_AI_DS.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
```

Note: This gives you the support of IntelliSense in Visual Studio and catching some issues at compile-time.

Comment: Aww, Karl, don't give him code that keeps the injection attack in there!